# Training/ Test Data with Time Series Model -- Forecast with Training Model, or with Model based on Full Data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, validation

Okay, I have a couple books on time series forecasting, but perhaps I need to read a couple more.

Here's my question.

You want to be able to validate a forecasting model. So you split the data into "training" data and "test" data --- to build a model off the "training" data and then use the test data as an out-of-sample trial run to analyze how well the model predicts future unknown data.

So, let's say a triple exponential smoothing model (with dampening) turns out to be the best fit model on the training data. Alpha, beta, gamma (and phi) parameters are optimized, initial levels, trend, and seasonality are determined. You test it on the test data, and the MAPE, ME, RMSE, MAE seem fine.

Now, here's the question. Is this model -- built on training data (80% whole data) -- parameters and everything -- is THIS the model you're going to keep for future forecasting (you will use the training model parameters with 100% of the data inserted).

Or would you think --- hmmm.. the parameter optimization and initial levels worked out well for the training data ... I'm going to re-run the optimization for 100% of the data now. See what I'm saying? Are you validating the training model, or the process by which you ascertained the training model?

Also, I tried an experiment whereas I applied an 80% training data based model to forecast the last 10% of the data .... vs. a 90% training data model to forecast the last 10% of the data (both had 90% of the data as historical inputs).

The RMSE and MAPE of the 80%-training model were 10-20% higher than the 90% model. So it would seem updating the model as new data comes in --- at least only based on this one observation --- might be beneficial to forecast accuracy.

However, the autocorrelation of residuals seems to have a major difference. The 80%-training forecast has an Auto-correlation of -0.017 among residuals in the forecast, whereas the 90% training forecast has an AC of -0.278 among residuals. I know the residuals are supposed to indicate the goodness-of-fit of a model, but when it comes to dollars and cents, aren't RMSE and MAPE really the gold standard (RMSE if errors cause exponential catastrophe and MAPE if errors scale linearly with consequences).

Let me know if this makes sense.

Also, as a brief aside, when using ets() function in R, it doesn't seem to always choose the best model based on RMSE/ MAPE/ or even AIC. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: I believe RMSE is about quadratic loss, not exponential. Also, I suggest you make your question stand out visually (use double asterisks from both sides for boldface font). To me it seems your main question is, in your own words, **Are you validating the training model, or the process by which you ascertained the training model?** I assume you understand how to do both but you are wondering which one to go for. The simple way would be to validate the model (as opposed to the procedure) and later allow the parameters to be reestimated whenever new data arrives. Do I get you question alright?

Comment: Perhaps there are three alternatives, two of which you had in mind. **(1)** Given a model class (e.g. all ARMA models), select model order (e.g. ARMA(2,1)). For forecasting, use the same model order but reestimate parameters based on all available data. **(2)**  Given a model class AND model order, see how well it does in the test sample (but no model tuning except for parameter estimation). Reestimate parameters based on all available data before forecasting. **(3)** Given a model class AND model order, see how well it does in the test sample. Do NOT reestimate parameters before forecasting.

Comment: In the last example, I think **(3)** does not make much sense while **(1)** could often be the reasonable choice.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the 1st suggestion is what I was thinking about. I was hesitant about recalculating the parameters, because I've heard a few times that 'constantly optimizing' the parameters (specifically alpha, beta, gamma for exponential smoothing models) --- ultimately may produce worse forecast accuracy then optimizing once. Of course I'm not an expert as to why. It seems like at minimum, tuning them every 3-6 months would do much more help than harm. I was wondering if I re-estimated the parameters, that would make the new model untested/ potentially overfitted, but looking back, probably not

Comment: Well, if you can sensibly believe that the data generating process (DGP) does not change as time passes, you will on average gain by including the new data that arrives. Neglecting them would not make sense. If, on the other hand, you believe that the DGP changes over time, then you could use a rolling window of the data and reconsider the model within a given class (or even consider other model classes as well), not only reestimate the parameter estimates.

Comment: Well, no matter what, every ARIMA and ETS model --- even if it's a fixed model with fixed parameters --- will absorb new data into its forecast of course. The idea was how often would I change the parameter optimization (both alpha, beta, gamma, in addition to the best estimated initial levels). A constantly changing DGP would probably benefit from more frequent optimizations --- I believe a stable DGP according to literature --- it CAN have parameters re-optimized with every new N pieces of historical values, but you're overfitting the random noise variance.

Comment: I will probably 'retune' the parameters every 3-6 months, as I don't believe the DGP changes fundamentally any quicker than that. As an aside, I believe it's possible for the model itself to change. I mean, it's extraordinarily common for any kind of product or business lifecycle -- when forecasting sales --- to form a sort of upside-down parabola. Explosive growth, followed by dampened growth, followed by stagnation, then decline, then rapid decline as new products replace it. In this common model, the model first fits a simple trend ETS, then a dampened trend later-so model change can occur.

Comment: What do you mean by "retune" the parameters? If you are going to reestimate them without reconsidering model order (i.e. assuming it stays the same), you would benefit from doing it each time a new piece of data becomes available; this will allow you to get more precise estimates due to increased sample size. If the model order changes smoothly/gradually over time, you might as well reconsider model order at every period. Each time a new piece of data arrives, you want to do the best you can, so why compromise? Perhaps you wan to save your own time, then this kind of compromise makes sense.

Comment: I think if you mean reestimate the smoothing factors alpha, beta, gamma and the initial level/ trend/ seasonality, each time a new piece of data comes in --- that's called auto-optimization of parameters. I heard it from professors on here and literature that such a system usually results in poorer forecast accuracy overall. Why? I cannot say I recall. My hunch is that it has something to do with overfitting.

Comment: It will not overfit if it is carefully designed. On the other hand, not using all the available information when building a model seems suboptimal in principle. When a new piece of data arrives, why would one limit its contribution to parameter estimation but neglect it when estimating model order? A priori theoretical restrictions could be a reason, but otherwise it makes little sense to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure why. I remember specifically hearing that auto-optimization of alpha, beta, gamma parameters after each data point (forget what the literature name of it is) -- fares worse than attempting to find one optimal model, and keeping that for longer durations. Perhaps I can post a separate question on here for that. Again, I'm not sure why the logic is.

Comment: A separate question could be a good idea. But perhaps I am just ignorant of the peculiarities of the exponential smoothing methodology and I am missing something specific to that...